# How to add bullet points in R Shiny's renderText?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using `renderText` to display some dynamic output in my Shiny web app. Now how can I include a bullet points in the dynamic output?

Comment: By returning a full "`<ul><li>...text...</li><li>...more text...</li></ul>`" response, perhaps??

Comment: @hrbrmstr thanks, but `renderText("<ul><li>...text...</li><li>...more text...</li></ul>")` doesn't work because the HTML tags are also output with the text.

Comment: Can you switch it to `verbatimTextOutput` - http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/shiny/docs/verbatimTextOutput ? Just realized my local example with HTML is using that vs `renderText`

Comment: if you know markdown you can also use the `includeMarkdown` function in a `renderUI`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Assuming you are using `UI.R` and not a custom HTML UI, you should be able to use either the `HTML` function or the `tags` function for this.

Please be advised I am writing this out of my head, so the code is untested.

```
HTML("<ul><li>...text...</li><li>...more text...</li></ul>")
```

Or

```
tags$div(
  tags$ul(
     tags$li("text")
  )
)
```

---

**Update:** I first missed the *dynamic* word in your question, which is why I only mentioned `UI.R` (thanks to @StephaneLaurent for pointing it out).

In order to make your bulleted list dynamic you should use `renderUI` in your `server.R`. This function expects the expression it wraps to be HTML. Then, you can specify in your `UI.R` where to put the list by using `uiOutput`.

The code would look more or less like this:

**UI.R**

```
#other elements before the list
uiOutput("myList")
#other elements after the list
```

**server.R**

```
output$myList <- renderUI(HTML("<ul><li>...text...</li><li>...more text...</li></ul>"))
```

You can find more information on `renderUI` in the [docs](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/shiny/docs/renderUI), and a brief explanation about using it for dynamic UIs in the [tutorial](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#dynamic-ui).

Comment: Yes but I think he has to use `renderUI` instead of `renderText`.

Comment: As far as I know you do not need any `render*` function for this. You can just put `HTML` or `tags` directly. Anyway, I had problems with `renderUI` in a prior Shiny version (0.7.0), as it was not rendering correctly special escaped characters such as `&uacute;`. Granted, that may have been corrected in later versions.

Comment: The OP asks for a *dynamic* output.

Comment: Oh sorry, you're right. I missed the dynamic word when I read the question. I'll edit my answer to include your advice. Thanks for the hint. :-)

Comment: @JdP, that depends on your needs, but I think you could pregenerate as it fits the html string that you pass to the `HTML` call

Comment: @GuillemVicens, yes that works. You can use: `paste('<ul><li>', paste(unlist(dynamicList), collapse = '<ul><li>'), '<ul><li>')`

Answer (score 3):

I often use something like the following function, and then wrap it in a `renderUI`/`uiOutput` or `renderText`/`htmlOutput`:

```
#' Format character vector into HTML bulleted list
#' 
#' @param char a character vector. Each element will be a bullet
#' @param ordered logical (T/F). If `TRUE`, return numbered list.
#' 
#' @keywords internal
format_html_list <- function(char, ordered = FALSE){
  
  seps <- c("<li>", "</li>")
  html_wrapper <-  if(ordered) c("<ol>", "</ol>") else c("<ul>", "</ul>")
  
  bullets <- paste0(seps[1], char, seps[2], collapse = "")
  
  html_list <- paste0(html_wrapper[1], bullets, html_wrapper[2])
  
  return(html_list)
}
```

#### Example

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  htmlOutput("bulleted_list")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$bulleted_list <- renderText({
    format_html_list(c("hello", "there"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdFaA.png)

Answer (score -1):

I just ran into the same problem and came up with an approach using markdown formatting.

ui.R:

```
uiOutput("myList")
```

server.R:

```
output$myList <- renderUI(HTML(markdown::renderMarkdown(text = "- item1\n- item2\n- item3\n"
)))
```

If you have a vector of dynamic items, you can use `paste()` and `paste0()` to dynamically construct the markdown for the item list, like this:

```
items <- c("item1", "item2", "item3")
paste(paste0("- ", items, "\n"), collapse = "")
```